# How to run notepad from a non-elevated mode in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, notepad++, notepad

I was wondering how to open a file with `notepad` or, if possible, `notepad++` from a non-elevated mode in Windows PowerShell.  By this I mean, how can I open a file using a command like `notepad $profile` without having to first have started the current session with administrative privileges?  Also, instead of using `notepad`, will it be possible to use a different program like `notepad++` instead?

Comment: I don't understand your question, PowerShell (and other apps) run non-elevated by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Start-Process` with the `RunAs` verb:

```
Start-Process notepad $profile -Verb runas
```

This will run notepad elevated.

To use a different program just specify it's path instead of notepad.

Comment: I've only recently started messing around with PowerShell (as in today), so could you explain what that verb thing is at the end?

Comment: Verbs are per file type actions. For example Print for a text file, Play for an audio file. You can view what verbs are available by doing this: `New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "C:\SomeFile.txt" | Select -Expand Verbs`. The `RunAs` verb invokes elevation.